# Project Specific Configurations for Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublime-text-2

Is there a way in sublime text 2 to setup specific configurations for different projects. My personal projects use different spacing and coding standards than my work projects and I hate having to change these configurations when I switch projects. I know that I can change settings - but I'd also like to be able to disable plugins and change key bindings.

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a good place to start.](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/projects.html)  Open *Project > Edit Project*, assuming you have already saved the project.  You can add settings to that file so that they are project specific.  However, syntax specific settings will override them.  I don't think it is possible to do project specific key bindings.

```
"settings":
{
    "tab_size": 4, // tab spacing
    // As stated by tamakisquare, it is not possible to disable a plugin for a certain project
    //"ignored_packages":
    //[
    //    "Vintage" // to disable a plugin
    //]
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured. There's no way to set custom key bindings or plugin settings per project. Hopefully in the next release.

Comment: Project specific plugin settings would probably have to be set up by the plugin author.  I doubt it's easy, but worth asking on github.

Comment: Found out you can turn off packages for specific projects. So now its just key bindings. I guess you could add the package as a key binding.

Comment: @d_rail - "ignored_packages" doesn't work when you place it in per-project settings. I have tried it myself and it doesn't work. [This thread on Sublime Forum](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8270) validates what I said. I hope this feature is added to the soon-coming version 3.